# What would the best way be to accomplish this

Tags: html, css

I need .left-arrow and .right-arrow all the way to the right and "1 - 6 of 7" to the left of them. I currently have 1 parent div inside I have the two boxes mentioned above.

I have an idea of how to this might be done but I'm not sure if it's the best practice. I was thinking about creating a another child element and placing "1 - 6 of 7", .left-arrow and .right-arrow inside of it. Floating this child element right would accomplish my desired result.

Please let me know if this is the right way of doing this this. Which approach would you take in this situation ?

I basically need the end result to look like the screenshot below:

[image]

```css
.homepage-h2 {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #050000;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
}

.homepage-items-p {
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #050000;
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.Top-Tech-Products {
 width: 1030px;
 height: 243px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.left-arrow {
 width: 34px;
 height: 27px;
 border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
 display: inline-block;
}

.right-arrow {
 width: 34px;
 height: 27px;
 float: right;
 border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="Top-Tech-Products">
  <h2 class="homepage-h2">Top Tech Products</h2>
  <p class="homepage-items-p">1 - 6 of 7</p>
  <div class="left-arrow"></div>
  <div class="right-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just experiment with it. What I often end up with when doing CSS is just experiment till it satisfies my need. If the solution you thought of works, then go with that one and test it out to see if it's stable.

Comment: I think you are on the right track with floats. I would put the buttons in a div  which is floated right, and float the 1-6 of 7 to the right as well (ordering will matter). Just remember that there are typically quite a few ways to accomplish things in CSS and as long as it works for you, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see a screenshot as stated in your question but here is the general was to approach this: one [Unicode Character](http://unicode-table.com/en/) based and one using [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).

```css
.homepage-h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #050000;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.homepage-items-p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #050000;
  float: right;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.Top-Tech-Products {
  width: 1030px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.left-arrow:after {
  content: '\276E';
}
.right-arrow:after {
  content: '\276F';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="Top-Tech-Products">
  <h2 class="homepage-h2">Top Tech Products</h2>

  <p class="homepage-items-p"> <span class="left-arrow"></span> 1 - 6 of 7 <span class="right-arrow"></span>

  </p>
</div>
<div class="Top-Tech-Products">
  <h2 class="homepage-h2">Top Tech Products </h2> 


  <p class="homepage-items-p"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> 1 - 6 of 7 <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this without using `float` is somewhat like this

With the use of `display: inline-block`, `text-align: left`, `text-align: right` and proper `widths` can achieve the same result.

** **RUN SNIPPET IN FULL SCREEN** **

```css
body {
  max-width: 900px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.homepage-h2 {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #050000;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
}

.homepage-items-p {
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #050000;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: right;
}

.Top-Tech-Products {
 width: 100%;
 height: 243px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.left-arrow {
 width: 50px;
 height: 27px;
 border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.right-arrow {
 width: 50px;
 height: 27px;
 border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="Top-Tech-Products">
  <h2 class="homepage-h2">Top Tech Products</h2>
  <p class="homepage-items-p">1 - 6 of 7</p>
  <div class="left-arrow"></div>
  <div class="right-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, that works.  Simple trick.